# What does "scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function" mean?

Tags: reporting-services

The expression

`=FormatNumber(Avg(CInt(Code.FirstSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value)), 0), 0)`

results in the following error message when I try to update my report in the SSRS Manager.

"The value expression for the textbox ‘textbox16’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function. The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a data set. (rsInvalidAggregateScope)."

How do I fix the problem to get rid of this message? I searched for the message but, for some reason, the search results are not making sense to me.

Update #1
The expression above was this

```
=FormatNumber(Avg(CInt(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value.Split("|"c)(0))), 0)
```

before I changed it to fix a different issue.

Comment: What version of SSRS are you using? I'm going to guess 2005; I'll also wager that you're using a Matrix report item. True?

Answer (score 4):

**What:**

Aggregate functions calculate their value within a specified scope.  So when you use a Sum function, this answers the question of which set of these fields you are getting the sum of.  The scope can be the entire dataset, or it can be one of the groups within your Tablix.  That is why you are able to use a function such as `=Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value)` both in the grand total row of a table as well as in any subtotal rows that may be present.

The second argument to an aggregate function allows you to explicitly specify which scope you wish it to operate on.  So within a subtotal, you could use `=Sum(Fields!Quantity.Value, "DataSet1")` to retrieve the grand total instead, often done for things like percentage calculations.  If you do not use a second argument, the aggregate function will use the default scope of that cell.

There is an MSDN article that outlines expression scope in some detail: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255256.aspx#Anchor_1

The error message 'Scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function' occurs when you use that second argument to have an aggregate function use an invalid scope.  SSRS's engine doesn't know which set of these fields to operate on, so it cannot proceed.

**Why:**

That is what the error message means.  As why does it occur here and how to fix it in this specific case, it might be useful to stagger out the expression and look at the arguments that are being used:

```
=FormatNumber
(
    Avg
    (
        CInt(Code.FirstSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value))
!!      , 0
     )
    , 0
)
```

This expression uses 0 as the second argument to the Avg aggregate function.  0 is not a valid scope, so the function generates an error.  Fixing this is simple: remove this argument or replace it with a valid value.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
=FormatNumber(Avg(CInt(Code.FirstSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value))), 0, 0)
```

Or even:

```
=FormatNumber(Avg(CInt(Code.FirstSplit(Fields!AvgLOSC4.Value))), 0)
```

Just depends on what your formatting requirement is.

You can also set the formatting at the Textbox level with the `Format` property instead of trying to do it the expression.

Comment: the question specifically asked "what does it mean"

Answer (score -2):

The Hidden expression for the grouping ‘Page’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.